# Send link to Careers application message

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, stack-overflow-jobs

Can we provide a way of sharing a link to view a message in the Careers site?  Primarily if we want to share a copy of the cover letter to peers so they can have an example.

Comment: As an employer or as a developer?

Comment: As the job applicant.

Answer (score 1):

We have no way for an applicant to share a message sent to an employer with other developers; we haven't really had any concrete reasons for allowing this. Sharing of a cover letter doesn't seem like a good reason; a cover letter should be something that's personal to an individual not something that's shared around and re-used...

On the other hand, if you really want to share your cover letter, can't you just copy/paste it to the intended recipient?

Comment: Laziness. Plus it's too big to share in a chat it is easier to just sent them a link.